# Fetch data for widget on iOS 14

Tags: swiftui, widgetkit

the data that I want to show on the widget is getting from API calls.
My question is, I can do it in the widget struct or I have to fetch data in the app and use app group to send them into the widget? Can anyone explain the process to me?

Thank you so much

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63976424/how-to-refresh-widget-data?

Comment: I think so @Asperi, thank you so much